# HTTP Error 405 using Twitter's API in python

Tags: python, twitter

So I've been following this tutorial to get Twitter Data using Python, but I've run into an error.

https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python

```
from searchtweets import ResultStream, gen_rule_payload, load_credentials

premium_search_args = load_credentials(filename = "secret.yaml",
                            yaml_key = "search_tweets_api",
                            env_overwrite = False)
print(premium_search_args)
print(premium_search_args['endpoint'])

rule = gen_rule_payload("twitterdev", results_per_call=100)

rs = ResultStream(
    rule_payload = rule,
    max_results = 100,
    username = premium_search_args['extra_headers_dict'],
    endpoint = premium_search_args['endpoint'],
    bearer_token = premium_search_args['bearer_token']
  )

print(rs)

tweets = list(rs.stream())
```

Thats my code so far, and I receive this error:

```
HTTP Error code: 405: {"title":"Method Not Allowed","detail":"Method Not Allowed","type":"about:blank","status":405}
Request payload: {'query': 'twitterdev', 'maxResults': 100}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\python\py.py", line 21, in <module>
    tweets = list(rs.stream())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\result_stream.py", line 222, in stream
    self.execute_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\result_stream.py", line 272, in execute_request
    resp = request(session=self.session,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\result_stream.py", line 110, in retried_func
    raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError
requests.exceptions.HTTPError
```

The Support forums say nothing about this error code, so I'm struggling to resolve it,
https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting

Edit: Endpoint is `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent`

I am running this code from a computer, not a server if that helps?

Thank you

Comment: Were you making a `GET` request when you should be using `POST`?

Comment: What is the contents of `secret.yaml` (without showing your keys and tokens) - are you calling a valid endpoint?

Comment: That is what I presume is occurring, according to the twitter api, the endpoint I'm using: `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent`, is a GET response. I don't believe I have a way to change it?


Here are some of those endpoints. I've used the search tweets All and Recent, since that is what is currently required
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index